# How to put footnotes in the page where they belong in a mdframed environment

Tags: page-breaking, footnotes, mdframed

I have a large bunch of text in a `mdframed` environment, that span more than one page.

As it seems reading the documentation, the mdframed environment put every footnotes at the end of the frame, by design.

Is there a way to put each footnotes at the bottom of the page where it belongs, remaining inside the frame?
I know it should be possible, using maybe the `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` commands, but the `mdframed` internals are too complicated for me...

Here a code sample  that shows the default behaviour:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}

    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[2]\footnote{can I appear in the first page inside the box?}
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[3]

\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's quite a problem: `mdframed` must know how much space is available on the page; and the footnote may or may not end in that page, depending on where it falls in the framed material. I think that some clever trick as done in `bigfoot` could solve the problem, but it's quite intricated.

Comment: @egreg, you are right, but only if we want the footnote to appear in the right page _outside_ the frame. I'm looking for a way to do it with the footnote _inside_ the frame, so basically you have to put the entire page in the frame (meaning entire_page = text + possible footnote). This should be more simple, maybe! I'll check the `bigfoot` package, thx

Comment: any solutions so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's quite a problem: `mdframed` must know how much space is available on the page; and the footnote may or may not end in that page, depending on where it falls in the framed material. I think that some clever trick as done in `bigfoot` could solve the problem, but it's quite intricated.

So, unfortunately, the answer is "not possible without very hard work".