# footnote inside itemize

Tags: footnotes, boxes, mdframed

I know that I should use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext{}` (or not?) for putting a footnote inside an `itemize` environment, but when the items are split on more pages, I want the footnote to be placed at the bottom of the page where `\footenotemark` is and not at the end of entire itemize block.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,titlepage]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{palatino, url, multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.85}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}  
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{40pt}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[topline=false,bottomline=false,rightline=false,linewidth=2pt]
\begin{itemize}

\item
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\item Minimální hodnoty $rPOD$ v odvětví lze nalézt ve Finančních analýzách podnikové sféry\footnotemark. Zde jsou vypsány jen hodnoty pro odvětví, která jsou zastoupena v praktické části\footnotetext{Data uvedená ve Finančních analýzách se neshodují s daty v dostupných excelovských souborech MPO. Pravděpodobně jsou dodatečně upravována. Minimální hodnoty rPOD tak budou brány z excelovských souborů, které jsou dostupné od roku 2009. Pro rok 2007 bude dosazena hodnota z Finanční analýzy.}

\item
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\end{itemize}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The issue here is not with `itemize`, but with `mdframed` (if you were not using `mdframed`, your footnote would be in the desired location).

Comment: Normally you can just use `\footnote` as usual in an itemize, it is the mdframed environment that appears to be holding them to the end we could try to ping Marco....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have no additions. Footnotes can be printed inside the frame or outside the frame. Whatever the footnotes are printed at the end of the frame.

Comment: so there is no solution apart of make two frames; one ending on the first page with footnote and second one on the next page..?

Comment: i didnt notice that its connected with mdframed, there was already a question regarding this:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59585/how-to-put-footnotes-in-the-page-where-they-belong-in-a-mdframed-environment

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to split the footnote because of an `itemize` environment. Cases where you have to split the footnote is when the footnote marker appears inside a box (from which the footnote text can't migrate out) for example inside a `\parbox`.